# Pythonic way of applying changes on closing a dialog window

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, gtk

*I couldn't find any useful resources for this subject. I hope I can find some guidance here.*

I made a dialog window class using Glade, Gtk (3.10) and Python 3. It has about 30 options that can be changed. In the init function I set up the whole dialog window and set the options to the current value. I also define a bool-variable that stores if any of the widgets was changed:

```
self.settings_changed = False
```

So for each widget I set up a function that catches the "change-signal" and does the following:

```
def on_checkbutton_line_width_changed(self, widget):
    #Set setting_changed to True so that the dialog knows something changed
     self.settings_changed = True
     #Store the changed value in a temporary variable
     self.temp_checkbutton_value = widget.get_active()
```

Now when I click "Cancel" on the dialog I just don't apply any of the temporary values. But when I click "Apply" I want all changed variables to be applied. **But here is my problem:** Of those 30 changed variables only a few exist and all the others would lead to a lot of AttributeErrors, because the temporary variable doesn't exist.

I tried avoiding the errors by using a lot of try-except functions:

```
try:
    self.dataclass.set_checkbutton(self.temp_checkbutton_value)
except:
    pass
```

Is there a easier (and shorter) way to solve this? I imagine that there should be a way to build a queue of changes that are executed after each other after clicking on "Apply", but my potato-like python skills have so far not helped me in solving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example that might help:

```
class MyWidget:
    def __init__(self):
        self.changes = []

    def cancel_changes(self):
        self.changes.clear()

    def change_name(self, new_name):
        self.changes.append(('change_name', new_name))

    def change_color(self, new_color):
        self.changes.append(('change_color', new_color))

    def apply_changes(self):
        for change in self.changes:
            print("{} - {}".format(change[0], change[1])
```

alternatively you could do something like:

```
self.changes.append(lambda: self.dataclass.set_checkoutbutton(value))
```

and then apply changes would be:

```
for change in self.changes:
    change()
```

Comment: I used the solution with the lambda function. Not only does it work, but I finally understand where lambda functions might be useful. A big double thankyou from me!

Comment: You're very welcome! I've found lambdas to be most useful as wrappers for other functions in callbacks. Useful in other places, too, but usually like this.